webix.toExcel($$("dataTable")) is printing inaccurate numbers
I am trying to export a datatable as Excel Format using this command.
webix.toExcel($$("coretableCDC"), {
  filterHTML: true
});

GUI - Excel
39E76 - 3.9E+77
39E78 - 3.9E+79
4E2FE - 4E2FE
4E300 - 4E+300
4E302 - 4E+302
4E304 - 4E+304
4E306 - 4E+306
4E308 - Infinity
467E1 - 4670
467E3 - 467000
467E5 - 46700000
467E7 - 4670000000
467E9 - 4.67E+11

But for a column ID, there is a different value in GUI and printing differently in Excel.
How do I rectify this having the same value in Excel as in GUI? In the above table I have given only one value as correct which is 4E2FE. I need the same to happen in other places.

if ID is a text, the only way to correct this is to change source data in such a way that they wouldn't be like hexadecimal numbers. Add any letter prefix or suffix to make ID a text. If ID is a number, convert it to decimal.

the ID is stored as text, as hex is stored as text, but when making into excel, webix is translating it differently. How to make webix.toExcel customize to keep it as it is?

Try to specify the data types and output formats, Have it read, no?

The solution is to specify the export type as text: exportType:"text", exportFormat:"@" (it's my guess, try it).
webix.toExcel($$("table"), {
    rawValues:true,
    columns:[
        { id:"year",  header:"Released", exportType:"date",   exportFormat:"d-mmm-yy"},
        { id:"votes", header:"Votes",    exportType:"number", exportFormat:"#,##0.00"}
    ]
});


You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps
